# cat heredocument copied everything besides function call

Tags: cat, function, output, here-document, namespace

I executed the following code in my Bash console in an Ubuntu 16.04 environment:

```
cat <<-'DWA' > /opt/dwa.sh
    DWA() {
        test='test'
        read domain
        find /var/www/html/ -exec cp /var/www/html/${domain} /var/www/html/${test} {} \;
        sed -i 's/${domain}/${test}'/g /var/www/html/test/wp-config.php
        sed -i 's/${domain}/${test}'/g /var/www/html/test/wp-config.php
        mysql -u root -p << MYSQL
            create user '${test}'@'localhost' identified by '${psw}';
            create database ${test};
            GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${test}.* TO ${test}@localhost;
        MYSQL
    }
    DWA
DWA
```

Everything was redirected as I desired besides the code in the last row (the last `DWA` which serves as a function call).

Why was everything besides the last `DWA` function call copied but only this stream wasn't?

Maybe some conflict with the `DWA` before the last one?

Comment: What do you mean everything copied correctly?  I suspect that you wanted some of your variables to expand and they didn't.  Why are you using the name of your function as a here-doc delimiter?  You know that this delimiter should be a unique string right?

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice these are conflicted, I thought the first `DWA` would be copied as-as.

Comment: @Arcticooling, so umh, did you expect the output file to end with one or two lines containing that `DWA`? And how many did you get? (zero, one, two?) I'm not exactly sure from the text, but your comment says you "thought the first DWA would be copied [as-is]", so I presume you expected to get one `DWA`, but only got zero, is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last `DWA` is being removed because you are using this as your delimiter.  The delimiters tell your shell everything between these matching strings is part of my here doc.  The delimiters are not part of the doc and are therefore stripped when the here doc is read.  The reason the `DWA` prior to that remained is because the delimiter must be at the start of the line.   I typically see people use `EOF` or `EOL` but this string can be whatever you want, so long as it is unique and does not appear within your document.

I recommend modifying to this:

```
cat <<-'EOF' > /opt/dwa.sh
    #!/bin/bash
    DWA() {
        test='test'
        read domain
        find /var/www/html/${domain} -exec cp /var/www/html/${domain} /var/www/html/${test} {} \;

        sed -i 's/${domain}/${test}'/g /var/www/html/test/wp-config.php
        sed -i 's/${domain}/${test}'/g /var/www/html/test/wp-config.php

        mysql -u root -p << MYSQL
            create user '${test}'@'localhost' identified by '${psw}';
            create database ${test};
            GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${test}.* TO ${test}@localhost;
        MYSQL
    }
    DWA
EOF
```

If you do actually want those variables to expand prior to being sent to `dwa.sh` you should unquote `EOF`

I find this page to be a very concise resource for here documents:
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Comment: Should I expand the variables prior being sent to `dwa.sh`? I think I don't because I use the heredoc just to install the script. I think these two variables will be expanded the moment I execute the actual function inside the heredoc (after installing the script itself with the heredoc).

Comment: BTW AFAIK, single quotes allow expanding them in execution while double quotes don't. So maybe you meant to double quotes?

Comment: Negative.  Single quotes will escape the special character `$` whereas the double quote will not.   For reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting

Comment: Oh, so it seems I confused escaping with expanding... :|